# php sort assocative

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort my array and I keep getting a result of 1

here is the code pleas help

```
            $foo = array(
                2 => "Sports",
                40 => "Parent and Families",
                43 => "Arts and Entertainment",
            );
            $foo = sort($foo);
```

I'd like them to be sorted by value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort doesn't return the sorted array. It returns TRUE of FALSE on success. The array is passed by reference. So call the method and just use it

```
$foo = array(
                2 => "Sports",
                40 => "Parent and Families",
                43 => "Arts and Entertainment",
            );
            sort($foo); //foo is now sorted
```

**EDIT**

Note however, that sort() actually reassigns your indices. You should use `asort()` instead of sort if you want to keep associations

Comment: I think you mean asort() (arsort is a reverse sort with index association).

Comment: @Czechnology yup, I mean asort. Did I type in arsort()? Apologies, drinks and a late night don't mix well with good answers :S 

Thanks for the edit @Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

If you need to mainatin index association, use [asort(array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR])](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php). Note the pass by reference on $array ( --> check manual what the function outputs).

```
$foo = array(
    2 => "Sports",
    40 => "Parent and Families",
    43 => "Arts and Entertainment",
);
asort($foo);
print_r($foo);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [43] => Arts and Entertainment
    [40] => Parent and Families
    [2] => Sports
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `asort()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php